# how do i compare a double to an array of double

Tags: java, arrays

How can I compare an array of doubles to a double?

In this case, I want go through the list of miles flown by each pilot and compare it to the average of miles traveled between all of them. If their individual mileage is greater than the average then return a true boolean.

> The complier says I can't compare a double to a double[].

Code:

```
public static boolean determine(double avgMilesFlown, double[] numMilesFlown) {
    for (double a : numMilesFlown) {
        if (numMilesFlown > avgMilesFlown) {

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you declare `a`?

Comment: Dan you are comparing array with single element , which no compiler in this world will be able to compare . compare with "a"

Comment: Looks like a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `if (numMilesFlown > avgMilesFlown)` to `if (a > avgMilesFlown)` you can't directly compare a number and array. You need to compare the elements of the array to your number. The for loop you are using assigns each individual member to the variable that you listed

You also need to put a return false at the end in the case that none have flown more then the avg

Answer (score 1):

In addition you could do the following:-

```
public static boolean determine(double avgMilesFlown, double[] numMilesFlown) {
   for (double a : numMilesFlown) {
       Double A = new Double(a);
       Double N = new Double(numMilesFlown);

       /*
        * Use the compareTo() in Double class for comparison
        * for doubles.
        */
       if (A.compareTo(N) > 0) 
           return true;
       }

   }
}
```

Comment: No need to box the values. `Double` already provides a `static` `compare` method that accepts primitive arguments.